# Refresh original url while using history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original Url: domain/dashboard.htm

I replace it using pushState():

```
window.history.pushState("", "", 'teachers.htm');
```

So now on address bar I can see "domain/teachers.htm"

But when I press F5 or refresh page then browser refresh "domain/teachers.htm" which is not exist in real and I am getting page not found error.

At this stage browser should refresh original URL i.e "domain/dashboard.htm" and show content

**Is there any way to do so?**

Answer (score 1):

Create `"teachers.htm"` page, and in the page load (javascript) method, redirect it back to `"domain/dashboard.htm"`, this way if anybody pressess F5, it goes back to `"dashboard.htm"` instead of `"teachers.htm"`.

Answer (score 0):

Save original URL and then replace it.

```
var originalUrl = window.location.href;
window.history.pushState("", "", 'teachers.htm');
window.location = originalUrl;
```

or Write

```
window.history.back();
```

then refresh the page

Comment: it Save original URL>change URL in address bar>again set location to originalUrl so at this point what happen is the cycle from beginning runs again and again